# запрос на вывод строк без дубликатов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица:
[image: bc[исходная таблица]

Как вывести (select) строки без дубликатов с минимальным временем?
чтобы получит такую таблицу:
[image: результирующая таблица]

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

Comment: Для получения результирующей таблицы работа с минимальным временем не трубуется. Может надо уточнить вопрос?

Comment: нужна группировка по строкам

Comment: но с учетом очередности появления

Comment: Минимальное время для уникальной группы параметров?

Comment: да именно так,  минимальное время для уникальной группы параметров

Answer (score 0):

Здесь агрегация по минимальному значению колонки времени, это делается с помощью агрегатной функции MIN и группировки по остальным полям, которые указаны в выводе:

```
select min("timestamp"), param1, param2, param3
from table
group by param1, param2, param3
```

GROUP BY группирует все поля, не участвующие в функциях агрегации, оставляя уникальные значения и выполняя агрегатную функцию в рамках сгруппированных значений.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой ответ объяснениями